# Getting placemark.locality from it's function into the viewDidLoad function (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am a bit new in iOS app development. I am currently working on a weather app that determines your location and then connects to a weather API and displays your weather conditions for the day. I am having a problem with getting placemark.locality out of its function so I can use it with the API to get the current weather conditions.

This is the function that gets the placemark.locality.
Please note that it is also in my viewDidLoad function.

```
func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark)
{
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    println(placemark.locality)
    println(placemark.postalCode)
    println(placemark.administrativeArea)
    println(placemark.country)

}
```

If i try to call placemark.locality in any other function or class except this function it says placemark is an unresolved identifier.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The context of your variable is your method. You can define a variable in your class (outside of your method) and stock your place mark 
myVariable = placemark.locality in your method.

After you can use myVariable